# Convert class attributes to UpperCamelCase

Tags: c#, typescript, https, data-conversion, camelcasing

I have a class in TypeScript that has attributes written in camelCase.
The instance of that class needs to be used in an http request body that deals with a webservice.
The issues is, the WebService's Backend is written in C#, and it's trying to access the attributes using UpperCamelCase notation.

How can I convert the attributes of a class from camelCase to UpperCamelCase when sending it in an http request ?

Example:

```
class Test1:

httpClient: CustomHttpClient;

public attributeOne
public attributeTwo

constructor(att1,att2):{
this.attributeOne = att1;
this.attributeTwo = att2;
this.httpClient = new CustomHttpClient();

}

sendRequest(){
const test = new Test1();
this.httpClient.post(url, test , null);
}
```

The WebService will try to access the body likeWise:

```
test.AttributeOne
test.AttributeTwo;
```

Therefore causing an error since no such attributes exist.

I don't want to change my attributes in TS to UpperCamelCase for linting reasons, etc..

How do I achieve this?

Comment: This is more commonly known as PascalCase btw.

Answer (score 0):

Try using HttpParams to set the request body attribute names to whatever you want. Example:

```
   const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('para1', "value1")
      .set('para2',"value2");
 
   const body=JSON.stringify(person);

return this.http.post<Person>(this.baseURL + 'people', body,{'headers':headers, 'params': params})
```

Taken from this https://www.tektutorialshub.com/angular/angular-http-post-example/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it like wise:

I installed an npm package called 'camelcase-keys' ( npm install camelcase-keys)

I pass my object as a parameter like this:

```
const body = camelcaseKeys(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(companyDetails)), { deep: true, pascalCase: true });
```